# openmodal ionic fetching params from html

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

currently i have a working script
**about.html** which have link to open modalcontent page :

```
 <div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let detil of detils">
 <a (click)="openModal({charNum : 1})">{{detil.contextOne}}</a>
 </div>
```

and in **about.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'page-about',
templateUrl: 'about.html'
})

export class AboutPage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public http: Http) {
 this.http.get('http://example.com')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
  this.detils = data
  });
 }
}

openModal(characterNum) {
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalContentPage, characterNum);
modal.present();
}


@Component({
template: `
<div *ngIf="character.image;else other_content">    
<iframe #iframeVideo width="100%" height="315px" [src]="trustedVideoUrl ? trustedVideoUrl : null" (load)="trustedVideoUrl ? handleIFrameLoadEvent() : null" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</ion-content>
`
})

export class ModalContentPage {
character;
trustedVideoUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

constructor(
public platform: Platform,
public params: NavParams,
public viewCtrl: ViewController,
private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
public loadingCtrl: LoadingController
) {

var characters = [
  {
    image: 'http://www.iframeexample.com'
  },
  {
    image: 'http://www.iframeexample2.com'
}

this.character = characters[this.params.get('charNum')];
this.trustedVideoUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.character.image);
}
```

i want to get the characters from api dynamically. how can i achieve calling the var character using http.get, i tried using http.get replacing the var lines. but it couldn't get the params value inside the http.get scope

Comment: What do you mean by *var lines*?

Comment: i mean fetching the data in modalcontentpage using  http.get instead of just declaring it statically